# Export-SPweb fails

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am trying to export a site (Document Center) which contains thousands of files.

After running for 20 hours, the export fails (see the error below).

The weird thing is that no .cmp file have been created after 20 hours.
The .export file is over 6MB

Here is the errors that I have in the .export file:

```
[2/10/2020 1:42:40 PM] [File] [Acadia Diversified I January 2014.pdf] [/sites/Acadia/Separate Account/Acadia Diversified I January 2014.pdf] [820d73e9-d214-49a4-bfee-6b9f60c05cca][Progress] Exporting File /sites/Acadia/Separate Account/Acadia Diversified I January 2014.pdf.
[2/10/2020 1:42:40 PM] Exporting File Version 1.0
[2/10/2020 1:42:43 PM] Exporting File Version 2.0
[2/10/2020 1:42:44 PM] Exporting File Version 3.0
[2/10/2020 1:42:53 PM] [Error] [-2146232832] [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException] [Error=Value=ClrException_System_NullReferenceException, Tag=0x0121d3da, Message=Exception=System.NullReferenceException, Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object., Stack=   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPSqlCommand.get_ReturnValue()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamStore.GetBlobsById(List`1 streamIds, Boolean doConsistencyCheck)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamHostBlobStore.ExecuteQuery(IEnumerable`1 queries), Chained=(Value=2147500035)] 
*** Inner exception:
[-1597300868] [Cobalt.ErrorExceptionTag] [Error=Value=ClrException_System_NullReferenceException, Tag=0x0121d3da, Message=Exception=System.NullReferenceException, Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object., Stack=   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPSqlCommand.get_ReturnValue()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamStore.GetBlobsById(List`1 streamIds, Boolean doConsistencyCheck)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamHostBlobStore.ExecuteQuery(IEnumerable`1 queries), Chained=(Value=2147500035)] 
[2/10/2020 1:42:53 PM] [Debug]    at Microsoft.SharePoint.CobaltStream.ReadAt(Int64 offset, Byte* pv, UInt32 cb, UInt32& pcbRead)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.FileStore.BytesFromLockBytes.Read(Range rangeToRead, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset)
   at Cobalt.Base.IO.StreamFromBytes.OnRead(Range rangeToRead, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset)
   at Cobalt.Base.IO.StreamBase.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ExportDataFileManager.AddFile(Stream fileStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FileVersionSerializer.GetDataFromVersionsRow(DataRow fileData, SerializationInfo info, ExportDataFileManager fileManager, ExportObjectManager objectManager)
[2/10/2020 1:42:53 PM] Exporting File Version 4.0
[2/10/2020 1:42:57 PM] [File] [Acadia Life December.pdf] [/sites/Acadia/Separate Account/Acadia Life December.pdf] [2be66388-432a-45c3-aaac-298ed4c2603b][Progress] Exporting File /sites/Acadia/Separate Account/Acadia Life December.pdf.
[2/10/2020 1:42:57 PM] Exporting File Version 1.0
[2/10/2020 1:42:58 PM] Exporting File Version 2.0
[2/10/2020 1:42:58 PM] [File] [Acadia Life HG Vora Subscription for 8 1 2017.pdf] [/sites/Acadia/Separate Account/Acadia Life HG Vora Subscription for 8 1 2017.pdf] [f7388638-0ec2-4637-ab53-7131f62b7060][Progress] Exporting File /sites/Acadia/Separate Account/Acadia Life HG Vora Subscription for 8 1 2017.pdf.
[2/10/2020 1:43:24 PM] [File] [Acadia Life HG Vora Subscription for 8 1 2017.pdf] [/sites/Acadia/Separate Account/Acadia Life HG Vora Subscription for 8 1 2017.pdf] [f7388638-0ec2-4637-ab53-7131f62b7060]  [Error] [-2146232832] [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException] [Error=Value=StoreBusyRetryLater, Tag=0x0121d3da, Message=Exception=Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException, Message=An unexpected error has occurred., Chained=(Value=2148734464)] 
*** Inner exception:
[-1597308888] [Cobalt.ErrorExceptionTag] [Error=Value=StoreBusyRetryLater, Tag=0x0121d3da, Message=Exception=Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException, Message=An unexpected error has occurred., Chained=(Value=2148734464)] 
[2/10/2020 1:43:24 PM] [File] [Acadia Life HG Vora Subscription for 8 1 2017.pdf] [/sites/Acadia/Separate Account/Acadia Life HG Vora Subscription for 8 1 2017.pdf] [f7388638-0ec2-4637-ab53-7131f62b7060]  [Debug]    at Microsoft.SharePoint.CobaltStream.ReadAt(Int64 offset, Byte* pv, UInt32 cb, UInt32& pcbRead)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.FileStore.BytesFromLockBytes.Read(Range rangeToRead, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset)
   at Cobalt.Base.IO.StreamFromBytes.OnRead(Range rangeToRead, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset)
   at Cobalt.Base.IO.StreamBase.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Cobalt.Base.IO.StreamWithInstrumentationScope.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ExportDataFileManager.AddFile(Stream fileStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FileSerializer.SaveFile(SerializationInfo info, ExportDataFileManager fileManager, SPWeb parentWeb, Boolean isGhosted, String setupPath, String setupPathUser, Byte setupPathVersion, String webRelativeFileUrl, Int64 size, Byte level)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FileSerializer.GetDataFromDataSet(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.DeploymentSerializationSurrogate.GetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.SerializeObject(Object obj, ISerializationSurrogate surrogate, String elementName, Boolean bNeedEnvelope)
[2/10/2020 1:43:24 PM] [FatalError] [-2146232832] [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException] [Error=Value=StoreBusyRetryLater, Tag=0x0121d3da, Message=Exception=Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException, Message=An unexpected error has occurred., Chained=(Value=2148734464)] 
*** Inner exception:
[-1597308888] [Cobalt.ErrorExceptionTag] [Error=Value=StoreBusyRetryLater, Tag=0x0121d3da, Message=Exception=Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException, Message=An unexpected error has occurred., Chained=(Value=2148734464)] 
[2/10/2020 1:43:24 PM] [Debug]    at Microsoft.SharePoint.CobaltStream.ReadAt(Int64 offset, Byte* pv, UInt32 cb, UInt32& pcbRead)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.FileStore.BytesFromLockBytes.Read(Range rangeToRead, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset)
   at Cobalt.Base.IO.StreamFromBytes.OnRead(Range rangeToRead, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset)
   at Cobalt.Base.IO.StreamBase.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Cobalt.Base.IO.StreamWithInstrumentationScope.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ExportDataFileManager.AddFile(Stream fileStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FileSerializer.SaveFile(SerializationInfo info, ExportDataFileManager fileManager, SPWeb parentWeb, Boolean isGhosted, String setupPath, String setupPathUser, Byte setupPathVersion, String webRelativeFileUrl, Int64 size, Byte level)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FileSerializer.GetDataFromDataSet(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.DeploymentSerializationSurrogate.GetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.SerializeObject(Object obj, ISerializationSurrogate surrogate, String elementName, Boolean bNeedEnvelope)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object topLevelObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPExport.SerializeObjects()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPExport.Run()
[2/10/2020 1:43:40 PM] [Progress] Export did not complete.
[2/10/2020 1:43:40 PM] Finish Time: 2/10/2020 1:43:40 PM.
[2/10/2020 1:43:40 PM] Duration: 20:24:39
[2/10/2020 1:43:40 PM] Total Objects: 41978
[2/10/2020 1:43:40 PM] Finished with 1 warnings.
[2/10/2020 1:43:40 PM] Finished with 3 errors.
```

Comment: How large is this site? If `Export-SPWeb` is running for 20+ hours, it is likely way out of the supported range for export with this cmdlet. But it looks like the file `Acadia Diversified I January 2014.pdf` has an issue with it's record in the SQL table. You may consider deleting/reuploading this file.

Comment: The site is around 20GB.

Comment: I would try removing that file, then try again. Nothing actually exports from SQL until it has the appropriate query executed.

Comment: What about the other two files listed before the export failed?

Comment: I'd focus on that single file, the others may have been victims (the last one was for certain). I would also suggest using a 3rd party migration tool to pull the data out of SharePoint -- it'll be faster.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation?